# Canvas circle is not being drawn properly

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to build an analog clock using a canvas. The first step is to draw a circle but for some reason the circle is not being correctly drawn. The circle is not complete. This is what I'm trying to do:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.style.height = "250px";
canvas.style.width = "250px";
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(125, 125, 70, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke()
ctx.closePath();
window["clock"].appendChild(canvas);
```

```css
#clock{
  width: 250PX;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">
</div>
```

I am trying really hard to understand why the circle is not being drawn properly. I need this to be dynamic though. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set canvas width and height attributes properly. Now you are using defaults (300x150) and stretching that to a square. That is why your image appears skewed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/width
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/height

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.height = 250;
canvas.width = 250;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(125, 125, 70, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke()
ctx.closePath();
window["clock"].appendChild(canvas);
```

```css
#clock{
  width: 250PX;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the width and height of the canvas. Note that these are not CSS properties but canvas properties.

```
canvas.height = 250;
canvas.width = 250;
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q5p7bro9/)

Answer (score 0):

You are making your canvas stretch out by trying to set the CSS properties, but not the canvas properties.  I've made the corrections below.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.height = 250;
canvas.width = 250;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(125, 125, 70, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke()
ctx.closePath();
window["clock"].appendChild(canvas);
```

```css
#clock{
  width: 250PX;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">
</div>
```